# \framezoom - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: beamer, graphics

I'm working on my second ever Latex Beamer presentation, and loving the clean, professional appearance.

All compiles into PDF format no problem, until I try to use `\framezoom`(the image is .jpg).  This fails:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Example}
\framezoom<1><2>[border] (0cm, 0cm) (2cm, 1.5cm)
\includegraphics[height=4cm]{02_pa}
\end{frame}
```

but works ok without the `framezoom` line.  I'm using Texworks, and the last lines of the console are:

```
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\amsfonts\umsb.fd")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tipa\utipx.fd") [3] [4] [5]
<02_pa.jpg, id=50, 2377.88374pt x 2055.68pt> <use 02_pa.jpg>
Overfull \vbox (4.0187pt too high) detected at line 77
[6 <C:/Documents and Settings/Owner/My Documents/Beamer/02_pa.jpg>] [7]
[8] [9] [10] [11]
Runaway argument?
border] (0cm, 0cm) (2cm, 1.5cm) \includegraphics [height=4cm]{02_pa} \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \beamer@framezoom was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.117
```

I've found several examples of how to use the command, and I can't see what I'm doing wrong.  Any suggestions?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/863/how-do-i-mark-inline-code) as Peter did in his edit. There's also no need to 'sign' your post as your name automatically appears.

Comment: Joseph thank you - you were correct!

Comment: I've posted this as an answer. (I wanted to check the code before I did.)

Answer (score 10):

I've checked the `beamer` code, and the problem will be the space you have in the line

```
\framezoom<1><2>[border] (0cm, 0cm) (2cm, 1.5cm)
```

after `[border]`. The definition of the internal `\beamer@framezoom` macro is such that no space is allowed here, or indeed between the two sets of parentheses. Try

```
\framezoom<1><2>[border](0cm, 0cm)(2cm, 1.5cm)
```

Answer (score 2):

instead of `\includegraphics` use the command `\pgfimage`. Then it should work.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Example}
\framezoom<1><2>[border](0cm, 0cm)(2cm, 1.5cm)

\pgfimage[height=8cm]{tiger}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

this worked for me.

Comment: Herbert thank you - it worked correctly once I had removed the spaces.